# While loop is looping more times that I specified it to

Tags: c++, class, while-loop, queue, simulation

I am making a clock-driven simulation program and, among other issues, my main while loop, `while(jobsCompleted < jobsToComplete)` is looping more times than expected/wanted. For example, if I were to assign 500 to `jobsToComplete`, the output at the end of the program would tell me that there were 505 jobs completed. I have tried to debug this one issue for at least an hour now, but to no avail. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <queue>
#include <fstream>
#include "job.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  ofstream cpuSim;
  cpuSim.open("cpuSim.out.txt");

  int clock = 0, jobsCompleted = 0, jobsToComplete = 0, probUser = 0, probability, id = 0;
  jobType_t job_type;
  int inWQ, outWQ, inCPUQ, outCPUQ, required, given, jobTypeInt, timeSpentInCPUqueue = 0, timeSpentInWaitQueue = 0, CPUidle = 0;
  queue<job> CPUqueue, waitQueue;

  int numIO = 0, numCPU = 0;

  srand(time(NULL));

  cout << "Enter how many jobs need to be completed: ";
  cin >> jobsToComplete;
  cout << endl <<  "Enter the probability that a new job is created: ";
  cin >> probUser;
  cout << endl;

  while(jobsCompleted < jobsToComplete)
    {
      clock++;
      probability = rand() % 100 + 1;

      if(probability > probUser)
    {
      for(int i=0; i<jobsToComplete; i++)
        {
          id = rand() % 1000 + 1;
          jobTypeInt = rand() % 100 + 1;
          if(jobTypeInt >= 50)
        job_type = IO_bound;
          else
              job_type = CPU_bound;
      required = rand() % 10;
          job *newJob = new job(id, job_type, inWQ, outWQ, inCPUQ, outCPUQ, required, given);
          waitQueue.push(*newJob);
        }

      while((CPUqueue.size() <= 10) && waitQueue.empty() == false)
        {
          waitQueue.front();
          job temp = waitQueue.back();
          waitQueue.pop();
          temp.setTimeExitedWQueue(clock);
          temp.setTimeEnteredCPUQueue(clock);     
          CPUqueue.push(temp);
        }

      double oneSecond = 1.0, timeSpent = 0;

      while((oneSecond > 0.0) && (!CPUqueue.empty()))
        {
          job top = CPUqueue.front();
          CPUqueue.pop();
          if(top.getJobType() == IO_bound)
        {        
          top.setTimeGiven(top.getTimeGiven() + .1);
          timeSpent = .1;
          numIO++;
        }
          else
        {
          top.setTimeGiven(top.getTimeGiven() + .2);
          timeSpent = .2;
          numCPU++;
        }

          if(top.getTimeRequired() <= top.getTimeGiven())
        {
          top.setTimeExitedCPUQueue(clock);
          jobsCompleted++;

          timeSpentInWaitQueue += (top.getTimeExitedWQueue() - top.getTimeEnteredWQueue());
          timeSpentInCPUqueue += (top.getTimeExitedCPUQueue() - top.getTimeEnteredCPUQueue());
        }
          else
        CPUqueue.push(top);
          oneSecond -= timeSpent;

          if((clock%60 == 0) && (clock > 600)) //every 60 seconds after the first 10 minutes
        {
              cout << "After the first 10 minutes:" << endl;
      cout << "Time: " << clock << endl;
          cout << "Number of jobs in the wait queue: " << waitQueue.size() << endl;

          cout << "Number of jobs in the CPU queue: " << CPUqueue.size() << endl;
                  job temp1 = waitQueue.front();
          job temp2 = CPUqueue.front();
          cout << "Job number of front wait job: " << temp1.getID() << endl;
          cout << "Job number of front CPU job: " << temp2.getID() << endl;
        }
          else
        {
          cout << "Job Number: " << jobsCompleted << endl;
          cout << "Job ID: " << top.getID() << endl;
          cout << "Job Type: " << top.getJobType() << endl;
          cout << "Time in CPU Queue: " << timeSpentInCPUqueue << endl;
          cout << "Time Entered CPU Queue: " << top.getTimeEnteredCPUQueue() << endl << endl;
        }
        }

      if((oneSecond > 0) && (CPUqueue.empty()))
        CPUidle += oneSecond;
    }
    }
  cout << "I/O_bound jobs: " << numIO << endl;
  cout << "CPU_bound jobs: " << numCPU << endl;
  cout << "*****JOBS COMPLETED: " << jobsCompleted << " *****" << endl << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

And as a less pertinent question, I cannot get my enumerated data types to print out correctly nor my IDs at the very begging to pass into `*newJob` correctly...

Comment: Everything in `main`? Seriously?

Answer (score 5):

Let's say it's been looping for a while and now `jobsCompleted` is 499 (and your `jobsToComplete` is 500). Okay, so this is the last loop right? Yes! But the incrementing of `jobsCompleted` happens within another nested `while` loop. So if that nested loop occurs 6 times, `jobsCompleted` will be 505 and then the outer while loop will end, leaving you with a total number of jobs completed at 505.

Telling you how to fix it would require understanding the logic of your code, but there's a bit too much for me to figure out. Maybe this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the code it's clear that this happens because you have a situation like the following

```
while (x < y) {
  ...
  while (condition) {
    ...
    if (condition) {
      ++x;
    }
  }
}
```

This means that for every outer iteration it may happen that you are incrementing `x` more than once, so you enter the last iteration (`x == 499`) and then increment it 6 times while inside the inner loop. You should debug that part of code to understand why it happens, explicitly you should check these two conditions:

```
while((oneSecond > 0.0) && (!CPUqueue.empty()))
if(top.getTimeRequired() <= top.getTimeGiven())
```

because on last iteration the are both true at least 6 times.